# how to generate spark time series data

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to generate timeseries data to create a test dataset.  For small test cases I use

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, Timestamp.valueOf("2014-01-01 23:00:01")),
  (1, Timestamp.valueOf("2014-11-30 12:40:32")),
  (2, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-12-29 09:54:00")),
  (2, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-05-09 10:12:43"))
).toDF("typeId","eventTime")
```

Which works file.  Now I want to generate longer series of data programatically.  However, I find that if I manipulate the sequence at all it errors when converting to dataframe.  It seems that the Sequence type is changing.  Here is a trivial example.

```
var data1 = Seq((1, Timestamp.valueOf("2014-01-01 23:00:01")))
val data2 = data1 :+ Seq((1, Timestamp.valueOf("2014-11-30 12:40:32")))

val dfError = data2.toDF("typeId","eventTime")
```

error: value toDF is not a member of Seq[Equals]
val df2 = test.toDF("typeId","eventTime")

How can I programatically create a sequence and then create a spark dataframe?

Comment: put ++ instead of :+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:+ is used to append an element not a sequence. So replace :+ by ++.

```
val data2 = data1 ++ Seq((1, Timestamp.valueOf("2014-11-30 12:40:32")))
```

`